# pnmtopng on large file

Tags: png, c, image-conversion

I am running `pnmtopng` on a 101M, 3000x4000 pixel PNM file. I get the error `pnmtopng: ASCII decimal integer in file is too large to be processed.` every time I run it. I looked through the source and it appears as though the dimensions of the file are too big for `pnmtopng` to handle. Without trying to edit and re-compile the source, how might I combat this?

Thanks.

See:

[image: failing to transform]

and

[image: pnm file]

Comment: What version of netpbm do you have?  I can't find that error message anywhere in the current "super-stable" version netpbm-10.35.97.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I have 10.68.0.

Comment: I downloaded 10.68.1 and cannot find that error message anywhere in that source, either, nor in libpng or zlib.  3000x4000 is a reasonable image size.  Perhaps you've got a bad BigEndian/LittlEndian situation somewhere. Can you post the first few lines (header plus a few pixels) of the pnm file?

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Nor can I. This is bizarre. Screenshot of the file is attached.